# When should I use a Form/ModelForm, FormSet/ModelFormSet?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

When should I use Form and when ModelForm? Also, when should I use FormSet and when ModelFormSet? It seems I can do anything with the regular Form/FormSet.

Answer (score 3):

ModelForm and ModelFormSet are DRYer ways to create forms (or sets of forms) for creating / editing model instances. They require less coding and it takes less time to understand what they do.

Of course you can do anything with the regular Form/FormSet, you can also create sites without Django, with pure Python, but using appropriate instruments is better, isn't it?